# Given $f(x)=ax-1$ and $g(x)=(x+1)/3$, if $f \circ g$ is identity then what is $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The function $f$ is given as $f(x)=ax-1$ and the function $g$ as $g(x)=(x+1)/3$.
>
> If $(f \circ g)(x)$ is an identity function, what is the value of $a$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think $f(g(x)) = f((x+1)/3) = (ax+a)/3+1$, not $-1$, right ??

Comment: I think the question should be $f(x) = ax-1$. It was this way originally in the body. The title has always wrong. I believe the body has now been incorrectly edited to be consistent with the (incorrect) title.

Comment: Ah good, that's been fixed.

Comment: Both the printer and the OP may want to check signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a misunderstanding.

**Edit:** 
$$fog(x)= a\dfrac{x+1}{3}-1$$
Let,$$y(x)=fog(x)$$
So,now,for to be identity function,
$$y(x)=x$$
$$fog(x)=x$$
$$\implies a\dfrac{x+1}{3}-1= x$$
$$a=3$$

Comment: The identity function is $x$.

Comment: $f(x)=x \implies f(g(x))=g(x)$

Comment: No, the composition $fg$ is the identity. So $fg(x) = x$.

Comment: Yes,I agree, the composite function is identity.,so $fog(x)=f(g(x))$ has to be identity. that is what i have written.

Comment: How is this what you have written? You've written $fg(x) = g(x)$, whereas what you should have written is $fg(x) = x$.

Comment: Thanks,I was thinking from a wrong corner.it is fixed now.

Comment: I've reversed my downvote.

Comment: Thanks.you are upvoted too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about what your question is supposed to be, because I remember seeing a minus sign in there before the latest edit, i.e. $f(x) = ax-1$.

If your question is indeed that (i.e. $f(x) = ax-1$) with all else being unchanged, then it has a solution. $fg(x) = a\frac{x+1}{3} -1 = x\frac a3 + \frac{a-3}{3}$, and this is identically equal to $x$, so by comparing coefficients, $\frac a3 = 1$ and $\frac{a-3}{3} = 0$ which both have the *consistent* solution $a=3$. This is crucial.

If, on the other hand, your question has $f(x) = ax+1$, then $fg(x) = a\frac{x+1}{3}+1 = x\frac a3 + \frac{a+3}{3}$. If this is identically set equal to $x$, we get $\frac a3 = 1$ and $\frac{a+3}{3} = 0$ which have no consistent common solution. So there is no answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$f(g(x))=x$$ for all $x$, it is true also for $x=0$:  $${1\over 3}a-1=f({1\over 3})=f(g(0))=0$$

So $a=3$.

Comment: should' it be f(g(x))=g(x)?

Comment: No, it si $x$ !

Comment: why? thats not an identity function.

Comment: Then which is it?

Comment: f((x+1)/3)=x this is what f(g(x))=x means

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: how is that an identity?

Comment: Then what is it?

Comment: @greedoid I think the question has been incorrectly edited. It should be $f(x) = ax-1$. See my answer please.

Comment: The incorrect solution here is fairly instructive - it's always better to solve it algebraically by comparing coefficients rather than substituting single values.

Comment: @Deepak Why is that better?

Comment: Your solution before the edit gave a solution to a question that had no solution (due to the typo in the question). Your method of simply substituting a convenient numerical value failed to reveal the error in the question (which meant your original solution was also wrong). Right now (post-edit), your solution is correct, but it is not ideal because it remains susceptible to the same issue (not being able to pick up on when the question itself is wrong and no solution exists).

Comment: I would hardly say thatsome method is better than other. I simply haven't finish the task i.e. I didin't made a check for that value.